# How to unpack Cython memoryview

Tags: python, cython, binaryfiles, memoryview

I have a memoryview of 32-bit unsigned ints that I would like to unpack into some chars, ints, and strings (or char arrays if necessary).

```py
cdef const unsigned int[:] bin_file = np.fromfile(rom_fd, dtype='<u4')
```

The first 192 bytes of this binary file is used as a header that contains metadata about the rest of the file.

I want to unpack these bytes from the memoryview (or memoryviewslice: `bin_file[:48]`)

Getting an int out of a memoryview is easy:

```py
cdef unsigned int first_int = bin_file[0]
```

However, I'm not sure the best way to get other datatypes, especially ones that span multiple entries in a memoryview.

I would like to be able to use something similar to

```py
cdef char[12] my_string = bin_file[40:43]
```

but that just gives an error saying "Cannot assign type 'const unsigned int[:]' to 'char [12]'".

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use the numpy `ndarray.view` function to view the array as another type. You won't be getting any speed-up from Cython (since you're just using numpy functions) but most of the ways I can think of doing it in Cython seem like they could quickly lead possible disasters.

```
cdef char[::1] my_string = np.asarray(bin_file[40:43]).view(dtype=np.uint8)
```

Note that I've specified that `my_string` and `bin_file` (not shown) are contiguous using the `::1` syntax. If this isn't true then your attempt to view them as a different type of memory is not going to work.